# Docker swarm can be accessed only on nodes, where container is running

Tags: docker, swarm

I'm currently running docker swarm on 3 nodes. First I created network as

```
docker network create -d overlay xx_net
```

after that a service as

```
docker service create --network xxx_net --replicas 1 -p 12345:12345 --name nameofservice nameofimage:1
```

If I read correctly, this is routing mesh (=ok for me). But I can only access service on that node-ip, where container is running, even it should be available on every node ip's.

If I drain some node, container starts up on different node and then it's on available on new ip.

---

**more information added below here:

- I rebooted all servers - 3 workers, where on of them is manager
- after boot, all seems to work ok!
- I'm using rabbitmq-image from docker hub. Dockerfile is quite small: `FROM rabbitmq:3-management` Container has been started at worker 2
- I can connect to rabbitmq's management page from all workers: worker1-ip:15672, worker2-ip:15672, worker3-ip:15672, so I think all ports needed is open.
- about after 1 hour, rabbitmq-container has been moved from worker 2 to worker 3 - I do not know reason.
- after that I cannot anymore connect from worker1-ip:15672, worker2-ip:15672 but from worker3-ip:15672 all still works!
- I drained worker3 as `docker node update --availability drain worker3`
- container started at worker1.
- after that I can only connect from worker1-ip:15672, not anymore from worker2 or worker3

One test more:
all docker services restarted on all workers, and all works again?!
- let's wait a few hours...

Today's status:
2 of 3 nodes are working ok. On service log of manager:

```
Jul 12 07:53:32 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:53:32.787953754Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-459b4229d652 as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 07:53:39 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:53:39.787783458Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-459b4229d652 as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 07:55:27 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:55:27.790564790Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-459b4229d652 as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 07:55:41 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:55:41.787974530Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-459b4229d652 as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 07:56:33 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:56:33.027525926Z" level=error msg="logs call failed" error="container not ready for logs: context canceled" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=b6vnaouyci7b76ol1apq96zxx
Jul 12 07:56:33 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T07:56:33.027668473Z" level=error msg="logs call failed" error="container not ready for logs: context canceled" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=b6vnaouyci7b76ol1apq96zxx
Jul 12 08:13:22 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T08:13:22.787796692Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-03ec8453a81f as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 08:21:37 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:37.788694522Z" level=info msg="memberlist: Marking dockerswarmworker2-03ec8453a81f as failed, suspect timeout reached"
Jul 12 08:24:01 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T08:24:01.525570127Z" level=error msg="logs call failed" error="container not ready for logs: context canceled" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=b6vnaouyci7b76ol1apq96zxx
Jul 12 08:24:01 dockerswarmmanager dockerd[7180]: time="2017-07-12T08:24:01.525713893Z" level=error msg="logs call failed" error="container not ready for logs: context canceled" module="node/agent/taskmanager" node.id=b6vnaouyci7b76ol1apq96zxx
```

and from worker's docker log:

```
Jul 12 08:20:47 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:20:47.486202716Z" level=error msg="Bulk sync to node h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi-891b24339f8a timed out"
Jul 12 08:21:38 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:38.288117026Z" level=warning msg="memberlist: Refuting a dead message (from: h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi-891b24339f8a)"
Jul 12 08:21:39 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:39.404554761Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP 10.255.0.3, mac 02:42:0a:ff:00:03"
Jul 12 08:21:39 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:39.404588738Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP 104.198.180.163, mac 02:42:0a:ff:00:03"
Jul 12 08:21:39 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:39.404609273Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP 10.255.0.6, mac 02:42:0a:ff:00:06"
Jul 12 08:21:39 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:39.404622776Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP 104.198.180.163, mac 02:42:0a:ff:00:06"
Jul 12 08:21:47 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:21:47.486007317Z" level=error msg="Bulk sync to node h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi-891b24339f8a timed out"
Jul 12 08:22:47 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:22:47.485821037Z" level=error msg="Bulk sync to node h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi-891b24339f8a timed out"
Jul 12 08:23:17 dockerswarmworker2 dockerd[677]: time="2017-07-12T08:23:17.630602898Z" level=error msg="Bulk sync to node h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi-891b24339f8a timed out"
```

And this one from working worker:

```
Jul 12 08:33:09 h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi dockerd[10330]: time="2017-07-12T08:33:09.219973777Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP 10.0.0.3, mac xxxxx"
Jul 12 08:33:09 h999-99-999-185.scenegroup.fi dockerd[10330]: time="2017-07-12T08:33:09.220539013Z" level=warning msg="Neighbor entry already present for IP "managers ip here", mac xxxxxx"
```

I restarted docker on problematic worker and it started to work again.
I'll be following...

** Today's results:

- 2 of workers available, one is not
- I didn't a thing
- after 4 hour "swarm alone", all seems to works again?!
- services has been moved from worker to other for any good reason, all results seems to be problem with communication.
- quite confusing.

Comment: What version of docker are you running, and on what platform?

Comment: Sorry, forget to add... Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be and platforms are all centos7

Comment: Do you have a firewall configured, iptables or external? Are ports 4789/udp and 7946/both opened?

Comment: yeps. host 1 & host 2 has 4789 and 7946 - both on both ones and there is also 2377/tcp open. host 3 has all open.

Comment: From the limited details you've provided, it should just work. You may want to consider providing commands and output from those commands showing how you know everything is open, how you got the IP to connect to, how you know it's open on the node but not reachable on other nodes, etc.

Comment: Hi, I add something new above. After reboot all worked for about one hour, but after that we are in same situation

Comment: What is the nature of your nodes? Physical servers, virtual machines, stored in a cloud?...

Comment: 2 of them on Google Cloud and one on Scenegroup cloud.

Comment: I'm quite confusing with this. Maybe something to do with data communication or docker's routing mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to docker 17.06

Ingress overlay networking was broken for a long time until about 17.06-rc3